# TFS 2010: Remove changesets to be merged

Tags: tfs, merge

In TFS 2010, when I want to merge files from one branch to another, I get a list of changesets that are yet to be merged to the target branch. The problem is a lot of these changesets have already been manually merged. So I am getting a lot of 'There were no changes to merge.' messages.

So I need to remove those changesets ( which have already been merged, i.e. no changes to merge) from the total list of changesets that are to be merged with the target branch. Please suggest a way to do this as I am new to TFS.

Comment: Why have changes been manually merged?

Comment: Why are you merging individual changesets?

Comment: We have a development branch and a main branch where the stable code is. So once a feature is added and is tested and given the go ahead, we port those changes to Main branch as well. But sometimes a developer merges manually, so the changes are already there in main, but still show up in the list of changes sets to be merged.

Comment: I understand this is a bad practice and we have planned to avoid this in the future. But isn't there a way in TFS to remove such changesets from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always be meeting the latest, or everything up to a specific changeset.

http://nakedalm.com/avoid-pick-n-mix-branching-anti-pattern/

Picking and choosing changesets to merge is not a good way to manage your code.

To unblock your merge you will need to discard the merger candidates that are no longer relevant.

tf merge /discard